# convert timestamp Date to javaScript date

Tags: javascript, date, timestamp

in fact, I called my java services from AngularJS and I go back an object that contains a date, for example:

```
{
"Name": "Jhon"
"date": 1465826400000
}
```

in my service java 1465826400000 date corresponds to Monday, June 13, 2016 14: 00 UTC and in my Javascript code:

```
var date = new Date (1465826400000);
```

and it gives 14-06-2016 4:00:00

that means one day lag between the two dates.

someone has an idea

Answer (score 4):

No, it just means you're looking at the result in the *local timezone* of your browser. If you look at it as a UTC date, it matches:

```js
console.log(new Date (1465826400000).toISOString()); // "2016-06-13T14:00:00.000Z"
```

Comment: thank you Crowder, it means that at my service java I have to convert the date to utc ?

Comment: @Cheps: It depends entirley on where that number came from. If you're going to use numbers (rather than human-readable strings), your best bet is probably milliseconds-since-The-Epoch (what you get from Java's [`Date.getTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime--)). Those aren't sensitive to timezones. When you use JavaScripts' `new Date(number)`, it will represent that exact same date/time. JavaScript's `Date` object has methods that you can use to get the parts of that date (or a string) converted to *local time*, and ones for UTC. Just use what you need.